# Firestore .get() doesn't get most recent data but an old version of it

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I simply try to get an object from the firestore database via a nodejs backend.

Here is my worklflow:

1. First I store my object:

   ```
   async storeEntry(entry: Entry): Promise<Firestore.WriteResult> {
   return this.client.collection(FIRESTORE_PATH_ENTRIES).doc().create(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(entry)));
   ```

   }
2. I modify it:

```
    async setEntryIncomeHistory(... incomeHistory: IncomeHistory): Promise<boolean> {
       ....
        await entriesRef.doc(activeEntryId).update(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({incomeHistory})));

        return true;
    }
```

3. And finally I try to fetch it:

   ```
   private async getLatestEntryDocByStrategyIdAndSymbol(exchange: string, strategyId: string, symbol: string): Promise<Firestore.DocumentData> {
   const entriesRef = this.client.collection(FIRESTORE_PATH_ENTRIES);
   const snapshot = await entriesRef
       .where...
       .orderBy("startDate", "desc")
       .limit(1)
       .get();
   if (snapshot.size > 0) {
       let result: any;
       snapshot.forEach(doc => {
           result = doc;
       })
       return result;
   }
   return null;
   ```

   }

My problem is that when I try to fetch in the 3rd step then I get the version of the object from step 1.
I could figure out that firestore uses some kind of local cache but the firestore get documentation says that it get the latest version by default:

*By default, a get call will attempt to fetch the latest document snapshot from your database. On platforms with offline support, the client library will use the offline cache if the network is unavailable or if the request times out.*
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Any help is appreciated!

P.S.: I put a sleep before I fetched the data and the database contained the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately I could find a fix but still don't konw what was the problem with the previous one.
Long story short: I used 2 functions for getting the document to avoid code duplication but when I put it together the problem disappeared.

Original code:

```
    
    /**
     * Gets latest entry by symbol and strategy id
     */
     public async getLatestEntryByStrategyIdAndSymbol(exchange: string, strategyId: string, symbol: string): Promise<Entry> {
        const entryDoc = await this.getLatestEntryDocByStrategyIdAndSymbol(exchange, strategyId, symbol);
        if (entryDoc) {
            return new Entry(entryDoc.data());
        }
        return null;

    }


    /**
     * Gets latest entry doc by symbol and strategy id
     */
     private async getLatestEntryDocByStrategyIdAndSymbol(exchange: string, strategyId: string, symbol: string): Promise<Firestore.DocumentData> {
        const entriesRef = this.client.collection(FIRESTORE_PATH_ENTRIES);
        const snapshot = await entriesRef
            .where("exchange", "==", exchange)
            .where("symbol", "==", symbol)
            .where("strategyId", "==", strategyId)
            .orderBy("startDate", "desc")
            .limit(1)
            .get();
        if (snapshot.size > 0) {
            let result: any;
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                result = doc;
            })
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And the new one:

```
    public async getLatestEntryByStrategyIdAndSymbol(exchange: string, strategyId: string, symbol: string): Promise<Entry> {
        const entriesRef = this.client.collection(FIRESTORE_PATH_ENTRIES);
        const snapshot = await entriesRef
            .where("exchange", "==", exchange)
            .where("symbol", "==", symbol)
            .where("strategyId", "==", strategyId)
            .orderBy("startDate", "desc")
            .limit(1)
            .get();
        if (snapshot.size > 0) {
            let result: any;
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                result = doc.data();
            })
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **force** the SDK to only fetch from the server (rather than use the cache at all), you can pass in a `{source: "server"}` object as the first argument of [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Query#get). The caveat to this is that it will throw an error when it can't reach the server - be prepared for that.

```js
private async getLatestEntryDocByStrategyIdAndSymbol(exchange: string, strategyId: string, symbol: string): Promise<Firestore.DocumentData> {
  const entriesRef = this.client.collection(FIRESTORE_PATH_ENTRIES);
  const snapshot = await entriesRef
    .where...
    .orderBy("startDate", "desc")
    .limit(1)
    .get({ source: "SERVER" });

  return snapshot.size > 0 ? snapshot.docs[0] : null;
}
```

Instead of returning `Firestore.DocumentData` all over the place, you can use [FirestoreDataConverters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.FirestoreDataConverter) to parse the data as your `Entry` and `IncomeHistory` classes. This will also allow you to remove the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someObject))` calls.

```js
const entryConverter = {
  toFirestore(entry: Entry): Firestore.DocumentData {
    return { /* ... */ };
  },
  fromFirestore(
    snapshot: Firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot, // NOTE: A QueryDocumentSnapshot always exists, fromFirestore won't be called on non-existant documents.
    options: Firestore.SnapshotOptions
  ): Entry {
    const data = snapshot.data(options)!;
    return new Entry(/* ... */);
  }
};

/* ... */

private async getLatestEntryDocByStrategyIdAndSymbol(exchange: string, strategyId: string, symbol: string): Promise<Entry | null> {
  const entriesRef = this.client
    .collection(FIRESTORE_PATH_ENTRIES)
    .withConverter(entryConverter);
  const snapshot = await entriesRef
    .where...
    .orderBy("startDate", "desc")
    .limit(1)
    .get({ source: "SERVER" });

  return snapshot.size > 0 ? snapshot.docs[0] : null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! It would be a perfect solution but the nodejs version doesn't accept this option parameter. I guess there is no point on the backend because you always need the latest one on the backend. But fortunately I could figure out a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the root cause was quite a rookie problem: the object initialisation was faulty and that overwritten the result from the DB.